# PHP Export to CSV file works on XAMPP but not Hostgator

Tags: php, export-to-csv, fputcsv

[image]

this code works on my offline version in xampp and automatically downloads CSV file. But the same code doesn't work on my live website in Hostgator. Is there something that i should change?    it just displays on the browser instead of automatically generating/downloading the csv file

```
    $delimiter = ","; 
    $filename = "depot_".$direction. date('Y-m-d') . ".csv"; 
 
    // Create a file pointer 
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w'); 
 
    // Set column headers 
    $fields = array( 'Depot Ref','Container No', 'Container Type', 'Check-In Date', 'Storage'); 
    fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter); 
 
    // Output each row of the data, format line as csv and write to file pointer 
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {                                                           

        $storage=getStorage($row["depotRef"]);
        $lineData = array( $row["depotRef"], $row['containerNo'], $row['containerType'], 
        $row['checkIn'], $storage); 
        fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter); 



    }

 
    // Move back to beginning of file 
    fseek($f, 0); 
 
    // Set headers to download file rather than displayed 
    header('Content-Type: text/csv'); 
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";'); 
 
    //output all remaining data on a file pointer 
    fpassthru($f); 

exit;
```

Comment: Open filepath right? Can you check your create a file pointer and check php version

Comment: // Create a file pointer 
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');

Comment: _"it just displays on the browser"_ - then your headers, specifically the `Content-Disposition` one, must not have arrived on the client side. Did you go check if the error log has anything to say?